# Iterating through a list and perform operations on a stack in Haskell

Tags: haskell, stack

I am self-learning Haskell. I have the following code that implements a stack using an list:

```
push :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
push x [] = [x]
push x xs = xs ++ [x]

pop :: [Int] -> [Int]
pop [] = error "Cannot pop from an empty list!"
pop xs = init xs

peek :: [Int] -> Int
peek [] = error "Cannot peek from an empty list!"
peek xs = last xs

isEmpty :: [Int] -> Bool
isEmpty [] = True
isEmpty xs = False
```

Now I want create a function that iterates over a list of integers and performs the following actions on a stack:

- If even, push to stack.
- If odd, pop from stack.

For example, say we have an input list of integers `[0,2,6,7,3,4]`. The flow of the function should be as follows:

```
Current Int         Operation           Result
0 (First item)      push 0 []           [0]
2                   push 2 [0]          [0, 2]
6                   push 6 [0, 2]       [0, 2, 6]
7                   pop [0, 2, 6]       [0, 2]
3                   pop [0, 2]          [0]
4 (Last item)       push 4 [0]          [0, 4]
```

This is what I've got so far, which obviously doesn't iterate through the list and doesn't really work:

```
operation :: [Int] -> [Int]
operation [] = []
operation (x:xs) | even x = push x stack
                 | odd x = pop stack
    where stack = []
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but `[]` is a linked list. Adding or removing from the end takes O(n) time. You should work at the front end so that your operations are all O(1) instead.

Comment: use finger trees to implement linked lists.https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=finger+trees+linked+list

Comment: @Carl can you surgically remove a node from a middle of Haskell list in O(1) time? if not, then it is **not** a linked list. nowhere in the Report does is say this, and nothing in the Report entails this.

Comment: In response to your edit (though it's not good to significantly edit a question after getting answers), there's a problem where you didn't remove the `Just`.

Comment: @WillNess: You’re using an oddly narrow definition of “linked list” there. And sure I can: `let (pre, post) = splitAt n xs in pre ++ drop 1 post` evaluates in O(1) time. You may be disappointed in how long it takes to demand the result, though.

Comment: @JonPurdy me and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), both: "This structure allows for *efficient* (emphasis mine) insertion or removal of elements from any position in the sequence during iteration." your code is neither efficient, not removal (it makes a copy of the whole prefix as you well know). linked list is a very specific pointer-based structure. haskell list is a high level specification.

Comment: @WillNess: That particular definition is valid, it’s just not universal; in fact it’s fairly recent, based on the modern idea of a data structure as a *type* rather than a *technique*, or loosely a “structure” in the algebraic sense. Historically, anything linked in linear sequence constitutes a *type of* linked list, so there are plenty of things often said to form linked lists (cf. “to form a monoid/group/field”) which don’t fit your definition—such as stack frames, file system blocks, skip lists, cryptographic ledgers, captured lexical environments with “parent” pointers, and so on.

Comment: @JonPurdy the article says 1957. singly linked, doubly-linked, trees with child pointers, also with parent pointers, etc. etc., are all low-level very specific data structures. queues, stacks, sequences, are all higher-order abstract data types which can be implemented in terms of the low-level data structures. that's how it's been for decades. Haskell just conflated all this: it took the great ADT promise and mangled it by putting the "algebraic" into the A instead. still nothing in the Report says the `[]`'s interface must have a particular implementation (IOW, have a particular complexity).

Comment: @JonPurdy or rather, what _did_ you mean by "That particular definition"?

Comment: BTW, [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linked-list/info) also agrees, as I've just found out.  there's also [*lists* on WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)) with a higher-level view, similar to yours.  and that's exactly what I was objecting to: though Haskell lists are presented in the Report as an _algebraic_ data type, being a built-in they are actually opaque and can actually be _abstract_. the definition is the interface in such cases, which does _not_ dictate any particulars of the down-to-the-metal implementation (which is what _linked_-lists are). @JonPurdy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, it would be easiest to implement this using a [`foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:foldl).

```
operation :: [Int] -> [Int]
operation = foldl step []
    where step xs x | odd x = pop xs
                    | otherwise = push x xs
```

However, it should be noted that your implementation of a stack makes these `pop` and `push` functions much slower. Since Haskell lists are singly-linked lists, you must traverse the entire list in order to reach the value at the end. It would be much more efficient to only manipulate the value at the head of the list, and then reverse the list when the entire operation is complete. This will turn your O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation into O(n).

```
pop = tail
push = (:)

operation :: [Int] -> [Int]
operation = reverse . foldl step []
    where step xs x | odd x = pop xs
                    | otherwise = push x xs
```

It should also be noted that this function is still not safe, because it's possible for the operation to produce an error if there are too many `odd` numbers. It would be better to use a `Maybe` in order to stop any errors.

```
import Control.Monad (foldM)

pop :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
pop [] = Nothing
pop (_:xs) = Just xs

push :: a -> [a] -> [a]
push = (:)

operation :: [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
operation = fmap reverse . foldM step []
    where step xs x | odd x = pop xs
                    | otherwise = Just (push x xs)
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to add a separate condition to check if a number is 0, then break the loop and print a message, how can I do this? I am fully aware that the type signature of the "operation" function does not support IO. (I edited the "operation" function as well)

Comment: You could use `Either String [Int]` instead of `Maybe [Int]` to exit the `foldM` with a message

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my code to include "Left" and "Right", however, I'm getting a matching error for the "foldM step []" part...

Comment: @jk_01 it's better to undo that edit and post a new question with the updated code, :) possibly including a link to this post for background reference if needed.